# ¿Cuál es el significado de "órale" y su origen?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, méxico

La palabra "órale" es usada frecuentemente en México en situaciones informales. ¿Cuál es su significado y origen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Efectivamente, "*órale*" proviene de la palabra *ahora*, pero más bien de su versión acortada *ora*, la cual no existe como palabra reconocida en el diccionario de la RAE por ser un modismo propiamente mexicano y que en realidad es una deformación de la ya mencionada *ahora*.

Durante la década de los 40's y 50's del siglo XX, la palabra *ora* era principalmente utilizada por las personas de estrato social bajo, y era utilizada como una interjección para denotar asombro o incredulidad:

> *Ora.. ora... y a tí que mosca te picó? por qué estás tan agitado?*

En algún momento también se le agregó la terminación *-le* con el mismo sentido, por lo cual la misma frase quedaría así:

> *Órale... órale... y a tí qué mosca te picó? por qué estás tan agitado?*

Sin embargo, la palabra *órale* ya se utilizaba también cotidianamente como una manera de incitar a alguien a actuar, de la misma forma que *ándale*, tal y como se puede escuchar en el seg. 8 (aprox.) de la entrada a la película [Nosotros los pobres](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPqLoFt6nNk). Dado que no existían medios masivos de comunicación que hubiesen podido difundir tal uso anteriormente a la filmación de la película, es muy probable que el origen de la palabra se encuentre en algún momento a principios del siglo XX, ya que debió haber sido usada de manera corriente durantes muchos años o quizás décadas, de tal forma que haya podido capturarse en el mencionado filme y recordando que ni los diarios ni la radio hacían uso de ese tipo de vocablos, por ser considerados medios *educados*.

Algo que es completamente seguro es que no proviene del verbo *orar*, como lo ha sugerido Jorge Campos anteriormente. No obstante, es un caso muy atípico puesto que, en su modalidad de exhortación, es un imperativo que no proviene del mencionado verbo, sino más bien del adverbio *ahora*, recortado a *ora* como ya lo había explicado anteriormente y que por lo tanto, es un imperativo de un verbo inexistente, al menos de manera formal documentada.

Actualmente la variante *ora* ya está en desuso y la palabra *órale* puede usarse de tres formas diferentes:

Como interjección de asombro:

> Óraleeee... está bien chido mamá... gracias!!

Como indicación de aprobación:

> Órale pues güey, así quedamos...

O como imperativo para exhortar a alguien a actuar:

> Vete a dormir escuincle... óooraleeee!!!

Desgraciadamente, mi explicación parte de mi propia experiencia como hispanohablante oriundo de la Ciudad de México y no cuento ni con la autoridad académica ni con el sustento documental que pueda avalar mi respuesta. (Soy ingeniero de profesión).

P.D. Una variante más reciente de *órale* (como interjección de asombro) es *uórale*, la cual denota un tono más jocoso. Este uso se puede ver en la película *Buscando a Nemo* con doblaje en español mexicano, justo en la escena donde Marlín y Dory son salvados por las tortugas marinas. =^D

Comment: *tí* no lleva tilde.

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas "inexistente" a "orar" cuando ahí está en la DRAE?

Answer (score 2):

Órale es un dicho que se puede usar como un saludo "Órale, ¿que pasó?"

También se usa entre amigos, para comunicar que uno está de acuerdo, por ejemplo:

> ¿Ya estas listo para irte?
>
> **¡Órale güey!**

La expresión viene de la palabra "ahora." Se corta la palabra y se añade "le". Otros ejemplos de este tipo de origen son "ándale” y “épale."

Comment: I disagree. Maybe something is missing in your answer. I rather think that "órale" is the same construction you pointed out but for the verb "orar" (to pray). It's then an imperative form of "orar". But, of course, that doesn't answer the OP.

Comment: +1 I agree it comes from _ahora_ and not from _orar_.

Comment: I really have no idea whether *órale* comes from *orar*, *ahora*, or something else entirely, but until someone provides sources, anyone remotely serious will be forced to conclude that you're all just making stuff up.

Comment: @MichaelWolf: touché! :) In my case it's my impression as a moderately cultivated native speaker, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

Como mexicano solo me vienen a mente dos formas de uso:

1) Como una expresion que se utiliza para exhortar, es decir para incitar a que alguien haga o deje de hacer alguna actividad. ¡órale apúrate!

2) Expresion utilizada para expresar sorprendimiento o al tener un momento de "eureka". Ah órale ahora entiendo... órale esta padre el aparato...

Sobre el origen, tiendo a estar de acuerdo con la idea de que viene de acortar la palabra ahora.

Comment: A veces escucho ellos de la vigilancia de mi escuela y gente como taxistas decirla antes de decir 'bye' cuando hablan por teléfono

Comment: @AdamBrown: Como lo menciona Trevor McKendrick en su respuesta, en ese caso se utiliza para externar que uno está de acuerdo con lo que se ha dicho "Órale pues, bye..."

Answer (score 0):

Yo personalmente creo que viene de los dos orar u ahora, es depende como lo utilices al conjugarlo resulta identico, pero es como se utiliza en la frase completa..por ejemplo: tienes qu orarle a dios...yo porque? Orale tu,orale andale. Ora imperativo dd verbo orar. Ora tu que te traes, ahi viene de ahora. Los chicanos lo utilizan solo en imperativo de verbo orar.

Y el sufijo `le` es la declinación para `tú`, segunda persona del plural

Comment: **Le** no siempre es segunda persona, y desde luego no es una forma del plural.

Comment: Le is a syntactic expletive: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19574/12672