# What is the grammar behind "¡Hágale pues!"?

Tags: pronombres, colombia, objetos-indirectos

Can somebody explain the grammar behind this Colombian expression? Assuming it's the indirect object pronoun, to what or whom does the "le" refer?

And why is it missing a direct object pronoun? Why isn't it *hágalo* or *hágaselo* or *hazlo*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this Wikipedia entry for "órale," I am concluding that the "le" in "hágale pues" is in fact a grammatical expletive and not an indirect object pronoun.

Describing "órale" here's what the Wikipedia entry says:

> The word’s origin is a shortening of “ahora”, meaning “now”, with the
>   added suffix “-le”, which is a grammatical expletive – a word part
>   that occupies a position without adding to the sense,[1] i.e. “ándale”
>   and “épale”

From a separate Wikipedia entry:

> A syntactic expletive is a word that performs a
>   syntactic role but contributes nothing to meaning

Answer (score 7):

*Hágalo* is do it by yourself
*Hágaselo* is do it to/for him/her
*Hazlo* is just do it.
*Hágale* is go ahead and do something.

**-le** refers to *Usted*

The pronoun can be omitted (hence is missing) since it would be too long to say *hágale usted pues* but in some cases the answer to **¡hágale pues!** could be **No. Hágale usté<sub>d</sub>**.

In Colombia this expression is used in the same way as [*upa*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b7UzNzC) usually to tell someone that is passive regarding some situation to go into action and do something.

Eg:

- Mother to child at 6:00 am: *Mijo hágale pues levántese que lo coge la noche pa' ir al colegio*. **Son, hurry wake up or you are going to be late for school**
- Wife to husband: *Hágale pues cambie el foco del baño que lleva quemado ocho días.* **Honey, get up and change the bathroom light bulb that's been broken for a week**

Other use is *on a dare*

- child 1: *A que yo corro más que usted.* **I bet I'm faster than you**
- child 2: *¡Hágale pues! apostemos.* (child 2 is accepting the challenge and starts running to prove it) **Come on and put you money where your mouth is**

And lastly (and thanks to Rodrigo for reminding me) **pues** is an interjection that helps express the sense of urgency or need for an immediate action. i.e **¡Hágale!** is less urgent than **¡Hágale pues!**

Comment: So aris said: What is the meaning of _hágale pues_? And DGaleano replied: _¡Hágale pues! Yo te explico_.

Comment: @fedorqui hahaha....exactly! Good example.

Comment: Note that "pues" is an almost meaningless interjection. In Chile we shortened it to "pueh" or "poh".

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo for reminding me that I had not said anything about "pues". I edited my answer.

Comment: Don't "hágalo" and "hazlo" mean the same thing ? AFAIK the only difference between them is the verb conjugation person of the imperative tense: the former is in 3rd person singular and the latter is in 2nd person singular.